# Regex to match even, non-zero numbers

Tags: regex, xsd, pattern-matching

I have the following regex: `[\-+]?[0-9]*[02468]$`
which matches positive or negative even numbers, but I also want it to not match '0'. How can I accomplish this? I can't find a way to translate "Only match 0 as the final number if there are numbers that precede it" into regex language.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider whether a regex is the best solution. Could you use something like `x % 2 == 0 && x != 0`?

Comment: Agreed.  Doesn't make sense to use a regex unless you have to (for some strange reason).

Comment: I do have to, and the "strange reason" is that this is for an xml schema.

Comment: What does 'not match 0' mean exactly? There are no 'integers' in text!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this one?
    `[\-+]?([0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*[02468]|[2468])$`

**EDIT**
This allows leading zeroes on both alternations.

`[-+]?0*([1-9][0-9]*[02468]|[2468])$`

Comment: Missing an escape for the minus sign, but otherwise I'd got with this as well. You could probably use a lookback, but I don't know if that's available in the php implementation of regex.

Comment: I don't think OP cares about leading zeroes. But it might be a problem if it doesn't accept leading zeroes on the 2, 4, 6, and 8.

Comment: `[-+]?0*([1-9][0-9]*[02468]|[2468])$` Dash doesn't need escape if it's first in the character class, right? This is probably easier for handling leading zeroes across both alternations.

Comment: @shawnt00 Perfect, thanks. I used the regex provided in your answer. I don't really understand why the '\' was included; the [\-+] part was taken from the software I was working with (oxygen xml editor). If anything, I'd have thought the '+' character needed to be escaped...

Comment: Dash is used for ranges except when it's the first character.

Comment: It should be a literal inside the character class. "Note that the only special characters or metacharacters inside a character class are the closing bracket (]), the backslash (\), the caret (^) and the hyphen (-)." [link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following, which seems to work: `[-+]?([1-9][0-9]*[24680]|[2468])$`

It appears to avoid leading zeros and doesn't use lookback.  Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Doesn't the '+' character need to be escaped? Unless there's a special rule for when it is located in a set. I'm not an expert with regexes.

Comment: I have been testing it on regexTester, and haven't needed to escape it, but that isn't foolproof.

Answer (score 0):

This would eliminate numbers that start with 0:

```
[\-+]?[^0][0-9]*[02468]$
```

So it would exclude `0`.

The drawback is it wouldn't work for `012`.

So it **could** be a solution as long as your numbers don't have leading zeros.

---

I don't understand the need for a regex here, though (you never specify the context).

It would be better (if possible) to check if the number is non-zero and even:

`( num != 0  &&  num % 2 == 0 )`